# Rename contents of Screen Capture dialog in web browser

Tags: javascript, screen-capture

I am using Screen Capture API to let users record their screen from web browser. It is done using following sample code provided at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Capture_API/Using_Screen_Capture).

```js
function startCapture(displayMediaOptions) {
 let captureStream = null;

 return navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(displayMediaOptions)
    .catch(err => { console.error("Error:" + err); return null; });
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

I want to rename dialog title from "Share your screen" to "Record your screen". Same for button, I want to rename it from "Share" to "Record".